# Circle effect in 2d array for lighting

Tags: javascript, arrays, computer-science

I am making a tile-based game and am implementing lighting. Lighting is done on a per-tile basis, where the intensity of light will be a default value unless it is near a light source. Before I update the lighting, I go through the array of tiles and check if one is a light in something like this:

```
for(var y=this.x;y<(this.x+this.h);y++){
        for(var x=this.y;x<(this.y+this.w);x++){
            if(x>=0 && x<earth.plot.length && y>=0 && y<earth.plot.length){
                if(earth.plot[y][x].top==13){
                this.lights.push(new entity(x,y,this.baseintenseity/5));//adds new light source to the lights array with very bright intensity
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What would be the best way to go about adding more light values around the light source in a radial pattern, with declining light intensity? Making a simple T pattern was easy, I just added a for loop under the part where I add the light. That looked like this:

```
var ln=5;
for(var i=0;i<ln;i++){
this.lights.push(new entity(x+(1+i),y,this.baseintenseity/(ln-i)));
this.lights.push(new entity(x-(1+i),y,this.baseintenseity/(ln-i)));
this.lights.push(new entity(x,y-(1+i),this.baseintenseity/(ln-i)));
this.lights.push(new entity(x,y+(1+i),this.baseintenseity/(ln-i)));
}
```

I'm really just looking for a way to quickly turn the above into a radial pattern around the light source. with decreasing intensity.

Comment: I think the correct thing to do would to make a Gaussian function, but I have no idea how to implement it. Anyone have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, I had to do a flood fill method.

```
var lights=[[0,0,0,0,0]
       ,[0,0,0,0,0]
       ,[0,0,0,0,0]
       ,[0,0,0,0,0]
       ,[0,0,0,0,0]
        ];
var tiles=[[0,0,0,0,0]
       ,[0,0,0,0,0]
       ,[0,0,0,0,0]
       ,[0,0,0,0,0]
       ,[0,0,0,0,0]
        ];
var dx=[0,1,0,-1];
var dy=[-1,0,1,0];
function setlights(x,y,b,dir){
if(b<=0)
    return;

tiles[x][y]=1;
lights[x][y]=b;
for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
    if (i == dir) {
        continue;
    }
    var newx=x+dx[i];
    var newy=y+dy[i];
    var newdir = dir;
    if (newdir == -1) {
        newdir = (i+2)%4;
    }
    if(newx >= 0 && newx < tiles[0].length && newy >= 0 && newy < tiles.length){
        if (!tiles[newx][newy]) {
            setlights(newx, newy, b-1, newdir);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This fills the variable lights with numbers of intensity, which I then turn into the intensity I want. Calling `setlights(2,2,4,-1)` does the trick and returns

`01210
12321
23432
12321
01210`